# Two tables in different subsections in a chapter shows differing table number. (No continuity)

Tags: tables, floats, numbering, subcaption

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{plain} % To force page numbering when using conference IEEEtran
\pagestyle{plain} % To force page numbering when using conference IEEEtran
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname} % For autoref to name subfloats as Figure
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table}

%%%%%%%%%% FIGURES %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} % Figures caption
\usepackage{graphicx}
\captionsetup{labelsep = period} % Figure 2. Caption (rather than Figure 2: Caption)
%\usepackage{float} % To place figures where I want with [H]
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.} % Fig.2 (rather than Figure 2)
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption, floatrow}
\def \hfillx {\hspace*{-\textwidth} \hfill}
\begin{document}
\section{Second}

\subsection{Second in Second}

\subsubsection{Second in Second in Second}

\begin{table}[H]
           \centering
           \captionsetup[subtable]{position = below}
          \captionsetup[table]{position=top}
           \caption{Blahblah}
           \begin{subtable}{0.3\linewidth}
               \centering
               \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                   \hline
                   \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\ \hline
                   30 & 0.75 \\ \hline
                   50 & 1.25 \\ \hline
                   70 & 1.75 \\ \hline
                   100 & 2.50 \\ \hline
               \end{tabular}
               \caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the FFT algorithm at different heights}
               \label{tab:dimFFT}
           \end{subtable}%
           \hspace*{4em}
           \begin{subtable}{0.3\linewidth}
               \centering
               \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                   \hline
                   \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\ \hline
                   30 & 0.28 \\ \hline
                   50 & 0.47 \\ \hline
                   70 & 0.66 \\ \hline
                   100 & 0.94 \\ \hline
               \end{tabular}
                \caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the GMM algorithm at different heights}
                 \label{tab:dimGMM}
           \end{subtable}
       \end{table}



 \section{First}

 \subsection{First in First}

 \subsubsection{First in First in First}

\begin{table}[H]
           \centering
           \captionsetup[subtable]{position = below}
          \captionsetup[table]{position=top}
           \caption{Blahblah}
           \begin{subtable}{0.3\linewidth}
               \centering
               \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                   \hline
                   \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\ \hline
                   30 & 0.75 \\ \hline
                   50 & 1.25 \\ \hline
                   70 & 1.75 \\ \hline
                   100 & 2.50 \\ \hline
               \end{tabular}
               \caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the FFT algorithm at different heights}
               \label{tab:dimFFT}
           \end{subtable}%
           \hspace*{4em}
           \begin{subtable}{0.3\linewidth}
               \centering
               \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                   \hline
                   \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\ \hline
                   30 & 0.28 \\ \hline
                   50 & 0.47 \\ \hline
                   70 & 0.66 \\ \hline
                   100 & 0.94 \\ \hline
               \end{tabular}
                \caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the GMM algorithm at different heights}
                 \label{tab:dimGMM}
           \end{subtable}
       \end{table}


\end{document}
```

Execute it and check the table numbers.

The table inside first subsubsection is table 1.

and the table inside next subsubsection inside next section becomes table 3. ? how can that be possible ? What is wrong in this ? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be due to having `\caption` before the subtables which causes the `table` counter to be incremented twice.  For some reason though, this is no issue if `\caption` comes after the `subtable` environments.

I have fixed the issue below, and also taken the liberty to cleanup a few things.  I have also made use of `booktabs` to make the tables look a little nicer and not like jail cells :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\captionsetup{labelsep = period}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.} % Fig.2 (rather than Figure 2)

\begin{document}

\section{Second}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  %% Try (un)commenting out the following two lines, and doing to opposite at
  %% the bottom two lines
  % \label{tab:Second}
  % \caption{Blahblah}
  \begin{subtable}{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \toprule
      \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\
      \midrule
      30 & 0.75 \\
      50 & 1.25 \\
      70 & 1.75 \\
      100 & 2.50 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the FFT algorithm at different heights}
    \label{subtab:dimFFT}
  \end{subtable}%
  \hspace*{\fill}
  \begin{subtable}{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \toprule
      \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\
      \midrule
      30 & 0.28 \\
      50 & 0.47 \\
      70 & 0.66 \\
      100 & 0.94 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the GMM
      algorithm at different heights}
    \label{subtab:dimGMM}
  \end{subtable}
  \label{tab:Second}
  \caption{Blahblah}
\end{table}

\section{First}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{subtable}{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \toprule
      \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\
      \midrule
      30 & 0.75 \\
      50 & 1.25 \\
      70 & 1.75 \\
      100 & 2.50 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the FFT
      algorithm at different heights}
    \label{subtab:dimFFT}
  \end{subtable}
  \hspace*{\fill}
  \begin{subtable}{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \toprule
      \textbf{h [m]} & \textbf{dim [m]} \\
      \midrule
      30 & 0.28 \\
      50 & 0.47 \\
      70 & 0.66 \\
      100 & 0.94 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{subtab:dimGMM}
    \caption{Minimum dimension of an object for it to be detected by the GMM
      algorithm at different heights}
  \end{subtable}
  \label{tab:first}
  \caption{Blahblah}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. But one problem is one table is sort of small and other one is sort of bit big and the positioning pushes the second table to go out of margin. Any suggestion on keeping both the tables withing the margin would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome!  If you have two tables with quite different widths,  you'll have to change the width of the subtable as appropriate (at `\begin{subtable}{WIDTH}`).  For example, try having one subtable with `0.29\linewidth` and the other with `0.69\linewidth`.  I usually try and ensure that add up to nearly 1 so the spacing looks good (it has to be very slightly less than 1, or LaTeX will put the second subtable below the first).

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked and I understood quite a bit now.